Finding $\min_{Q^TQ = I}(n Tr((Q^T \Lambda Q)^2) - Tr(Q^T \Lambda Q)^2)$
Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $c > 1$ and $T = T (n) = \lceil cn \rceil$. Let $p \in (0, 1)$. Given
diagonal $T \times T$ matrix $\Lambda$ with diagonal entries $\lambda_j =
j^p$, $j = 1, \ldots, T$, let $\gamma_n$ be the minimum of
$$f(Q) = n {Tr} ((Q^T
\Lambda Q)^2) - {Tr} (Q^T \Lambda Q)^2$$
over all $T \times n$ matrices $Q$ with $Q^T Q = I$. I'm interested in whether $\gamma_n \rightarrow \infty$,
and at what rate. I suspect $\gamma_n \asymp n^{2 p + 2}$ since this is true
if we take the minimum over $Q$ with standard basis vectors as columns, but
I'm not sure how to prove this. The equation from Lagrange
multipliers is $(I - QQ^T)\nabla f(Q) = 0$, which reads
$$(I - QQ^T) \Lambda Q \left( Q^T \Lambda Q - \frac{{Tr}
(Q^T \Lambda Q)}{n} I \right) = 0.$$
If $Q^T \Lambda Q - \frac{{Tr} (Q^T
\Lambda Q)}{n} I$ were invertible, we could deduce $(I - QQ^T) \Lambda Q = 0$,
which is equivalent to $\Lambda : Q \rightarrow Q$, which is
equivalent to saying that the columns of $Q$ are eigenvectors of $\Lambda$.
But from numerical experiments, it seems that the minimum value is smaller than the minimum over only $Q$ with standard basis vectors as columns. It also appears that $\frac{\gamma_n}{n^{2p + 2}}$ converges to a constant $L = L(c)$.

Are you minimizing $n {\rm Tr} ((Q^T
\Lambda Q)^2) - {\rm Tr} (Q^T \Lambda Q)^2$ w.r.t. $Q$?

Yes with respect to all $T \times n$ real matrices $Q$ with $Q^T Q = I$.

OK and also it is not the case that $QQ^T=I$ right?

@TedBlack No. In fact, $QQ^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of the columns of $Q$, which is never $I$ since $T > n$.

The answer depends on the range of $c$. When $c\ge 2$, $\gamma_n$ is always zero. When $1 \le c < 2$, as you expected, $\gamma_n = O(n^{2p+2})$.
Proof. If we denote the matrix $X=Q^T \Lambda Q$, we know that $X$ is symmetric, so $X$ can be diagonalized: $X=P^{-1} diag(x_1,\dots,x_n)P$ which $x_i$ are real numbers. Thus
$$f(Q)=n\mathrm{tr}(X^2)-\mathrm{tr}(X)^2=n\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}-({\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}})^2=\sum_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$$
(Note that the property of trace: $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$)
In Case $c\ge 2$: We construct the $T\times n$ matrix $Q$ such that $Q^T Q=I$ and $f(Q)=0$.
Let $k=n^p, S=diag(1^p,2^p,\dots,n^p), T=diag((n+1)^p,(n+2)^p,\dots,(2n)^p), G=S+T-kI$. Then $kG-ST=(kI-S)(T-kI)$ is a diagonal matrix with $(i,i)$-entry $((n+i)^p-n^p)(n^p-i^p)$, which is nonnegative. Thus there is a symmetric matrix $F$ that $F^2=FF^T=kG-ST$. Denote the $2n\times 2n$ matrix $R=\begin{bmatrix}kI&F\\F&G\end{bmatrix}$. Its characteristic polynomial is $$\mathrm{det}(\lambda I-R)=\mathrm{det}((\lambda-k)(\lambda I-G)-F^2)=\mathrm{det}((\lambda I-S)(\lambda I-T))$$
Thus $R$ is similar to $diag(S,T)$. In addition, if denote $U=diag((2n+1)^p,\dots,T^p)$ ($U$ is $0\times 0$ matrix, or say nothing, if $T=2n$), then $diag(R,U)$ is similar to $\Lambda$. Because both $diag(R,U)$ and $\Lambda$ are symmetric, there is orthogonal matrix $O$ that $O^T \Lambda O=diag(R,U)$. If we choose $Q$ to be the first $n$ columns of $O$, that is $Q=O\begin{bmatrix}I\\0\end{bmatrix}$, then $Q^T Q=I$, $X=Q^T \Lambda Q=kI$. Since all eigenvalues of $X$ are the same, we get $f(Q)=0$. It is obvious that $f(Q)\ge 0$ for arbitrary $Q$, thus $\gamma_n=0$.
In Case $c < 2$: We use the Poincare separation theorem (also called Cauchy interlacing theorem, see Wikipedia).
Lemma.(Poincare separation theorem) If $A$ is $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, $B$ is $n \times r$ matrix that $B^T B=I$, denote $\lambda_1\le \cdots \le \lambda_n$ eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu_1 \le \cdots \le \mu_r$ eigenvalues of $B^T AB$, then $\lambda_i \le \mu_i \le \lambda_{i+n-r}$.
In this problem we have denoted $x_1 \le \dots \le x_n$ eigenvalues of $X=Q^T \Lambda Q$. The Lemma shows $i^p \le x_i \le (i+T-n)^p$. Let $s=\frac{2-c}{3}, t=\lfloor sn \rfloor$, then $x_t\le (t+T-n)^p, x_{n-t} \ge (n-t)^p$. Thus
$$f(Q) \ge \sum_{i \le t\\ j \ge n-t}(x_j - x_i)^2 \ge t^2((n-t)^p-(t+T-n)^p)^2\rightarrow s^2((1-s)^p-(1-2s)^p)^2 n^{2p+2}$$
as $n$ goes to $+\infty$. In this way we get a lower bound of $\gamma_n$. If we choose $Q=\begin{bmatrix}I\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ simply, then $f(Q)=\sum_{i<j}(i^p - j^p)^2\rightarrow \frac{p^2}{(2p+1)(p+1)^2}n^{2p+2}$. In conclusion, we have shown there are constants $c_1,c_2$ that $c_1 n^{2p+2}<\gamma_n<c_2 n^{2p+2}$, so $\gamma_n=O(n^{2p+2})$ as we claimed. $\blacksquare$
